# Scripts not working as they should in C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Got a few issues with using Unity 2d scripting. I have sprite factory, and currently have 2 scripts. One is for running, one is for attack. Problems I am having are the following:

1) My character runs perfectly fine when moving right. When he runs in the left direction, the idle animation is always set to the right. So when he stops running left, it automatically moves the character back in the right direction when hes finished running

2) I have an attack script. This script works fine when scripted alone i.e. Attack.cs. However, when I activate my walk script aswell, the attack animation drops out completely. Do i need to merge the codes together?

3) Furthermore, I have 3 set of attacks, which I wish to program as the letter A. My character initiates the first attack fine, but as it is 3 sets of attack, the user would need to press the attack 3 times to initiate the 3 attacks. Should the character do 2 attacks, it should reset back to its initial attack.

Any recommendation with how to get profecient in C# would also be beneficial because i suck at Unity coding  =(

My Code (Attack):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using FactorySprite = SpriteFactory.Sprite;
public class Attack : MonoBehaviour {

// you forgot to set name of variable representing your sprite
private FactorySprite sprite;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sprite = GetComponent<FactorySprite> (); // Edited
}
void Update () 
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) 
    {
        sprite.Play("Attack");
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;
        pos.x += Time.deltaTime * 1;
        transform.position = pos;
    }
}
}
```

My Code (Run)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using FactorySprite = SpriteFactory.Sprite;
public class Walk : MonoBehaviour {

// you forgot to set name of variable representing your sprite
private FactorySprite sprite;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    sprite = GetComponent<FactorySprite> (); // Edited
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {


            if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) {
                    sprite.Play ("Walk"); // heh, remember C# is case sensitive :)
                    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
                    pos.x += Time.deltaTime * 6;
                    transform.position = pos;

            } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) {
                    sprite.Play ("Walk0"); // heh, remember C# is case sensitive :)
                    Vector3 pos = transform.position;
                    pos.x += Time.deltaTime * -6;
                    transform.position = pos;




            } else {
                    sprite.Stop ();
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should consider using state machine to manage your character position. In fact, it is a classic example of state machine usefulness. The book "Game Programming Patterns" [has a great chapter about it](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html); in fact, the very example that is used there is *very* close to the code that you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

In the update function of the walk script you call sprite.stop() wich will stop the attack animation.

You could check if the active animation is Walk or Walk0 to not stop other animations.
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animation.IsPlaying.html

Solution could be something like this (untested):

```
Animation anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();
if (anim.IsPlaying("Walk") || anim.IsPlaying("Walk0")) {
 sprite.Stop();
}
```

Or rather since you are using "Sprite Factory" as far as I can see from your code:

```
if (sprite.IsAnimationPlaying(1) || sprite.IsAnimationPlaying(2)) {
 sprite.Stop();
}
```

Assuming in this case that the animationIndex for "Walk" is 1 and "Walk0" is 2.
You can read more about IsAnimationPlaying here: http://www.guavaman.com/projects/spritefactory/docs/pages/classes/Sprite-IsAnimationPlaying.html

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply. This actually has solved the issue. If i remove the "sprite.stop()" from the code, the attack appears fine, however, the character runs continously loops, and doesnt stand idle   once i let go of the left or right key#

Comment: I'm glad it worked, I've added a possible (but untested) solution.

Comment: This has worked somewhat. The attack animation works, but now the running has dropped out? :/

Comment: You could also just check if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.RightArrow)) sprite.Stop(); so it would stop whatever animation is playing when you release that key. ofcourse also add it with leftArrow and whatever other key presses/releases you want to start/stop animations on.